# How to write a DQL select statement to search some, but not all the entities in a single table inheritance table

Tags: doctrine-orm

So I have 3 entities within one table.  I need to be able to search 2 out of the 3 entities in one select statement, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `INSTANCE OF` operator in your dql query like this (where `User` is your base class):

```
$em->createQuery('
    SELECT u 
    FROM Entity\User u 
    WHERE (u INSTANCE OF Entity\Manager OR u INSTANCE OF Entity\Customer)
');
```

Doctrine translates this in the sql query in a `WHERE user.type = '...'` condition.

See [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) for more details on the dql query syntax.

Comment: Note that when working with a discriminator map you might need to use the discriminator value, you can get this in your repository like this: `$this->getClassMetadata()->discriminatorValue`

Answer (score 5):

The answer for multiple instances actually doesn't work. You would have to do something like this to check for multiple instances.

```
$classes = ['Entity\Manager', 'Entity\Customer'];
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
->where('u.id > 10') //an arbitrary condition, to show it can be combined with multiple instances tests
->andWhere("u INSTANCE OF ('" . implode("','", $classes) . "')");
```

Comment: `$qb->expr()->isInstanceOf('u', '('.implode(',', $classes_names).')')` See more: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/4462

Answer (score 2):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504680/doctrine-2-how-to-write-a-dql-select-statement-to-search-some-but-not-all-the#comment33696432_7506698) by [flu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/601386/flu), if you want to retrieve some entities from different instances with a QueryBuilder instead of a DQL query, you can use an array as parameter:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
    ->where('u.id > 10') //an arbitrary condition, to show it can be combined with multiple instances tests
    ->andWhere('u INSTANCE OF :classes')
    ->setParameter('classes', ['Entity\Manager', 'Entity\Customer'])
;
```